# Appending Excel Data Validation Menus based on Cell Contents?

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I maintain a log of schools that my team has worked with that way we can track program participation over time. In the current workbook, users select the County they served in column H, then using the indirect function, a data validation list appears for column I with a list of schools from that county (named ranges). I've added code so that multiple school selections can be concatenated for the cell in column I. However, if multiple counties were served, I have users select "Multiple" from column H and then they have to search through the entire list of schools in the state for column I.

The school lists are pulled from another sheet where I have all schools in the state listed by county abbreviation, then district, then school name.

Would it be possible to allow users to concatenate a list of counties in column H, then generate a data validation list for column I where the school lists for multiple counties can be appended based on the contents of the cell in column H?

For example, if a user selected "Cty1" and "Cty3" in column H, in column I they would be able to select from a data validation menu listing all the schools in counties 1 and 3.

I've gotten as far as using the following for data validation:

=INDEX('School list sheet'!$E$3:$E$1300,MATCH(LEFT('Data entry sheet'!$H2,4),'School list sheet!$B$3:$B$1300,0)):INDEX('School list sheet'!$E$3:$E$1300,MATCH(LEFT('Data entry sheet'!$H2,4),'School list sheet'!$B$3:$B$1300,1))

where I can generate a list based on the first concatenated county, but I'm not sure how to search through the string for others without becoming impossibly complicated.

[Screenshot of current School Selection Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcn3t.png)

If it helps, this is the code I am currently using to allow concatenation of multiple selections and to be able to remove values by re-selecting them:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Allows users to select multiple values from drop-down menus for the following fields:
    'Additional Support
    'Schools Served
    'Student Grades
    'Teacher Grades
'Code also removes previous entries when selected again for ease of editing
    
    'Define variables
    Dim DVMenus As Range
    Dim CurrentValue As String
    Dim NextValue As String
    
    'Allow macro to modify protected sheets
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    
    'If multiple cells will be changed at once, cancel
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    'If any errors occur
    On Error Resume Next
    
    'Allows access to data validation menus
    Set DVMenus = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    If DVMenus Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    'Specify which range should have functionality
    If Target.Column = 5 _
        Or Target.Column = 9 _
        Or Target.Column = 11 _
        Or Target.Column = 13 Then
    
    'Stores current cell contents and last selection so that both values can be referenced
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, DVMenus) Is Nothing Then
        NextValue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        CurrentValue = Target.Value
        Target.Value = NextValue
        
        'If not blank
        If CurrentValue <> "" Then
            If NextValue <> "" Then
                
                'If cell contents and last selection are the same
                If CurrentValue = NextValue Then
                    Target.Value = ""
                    'Remove the selection
                
                'If last selection is already at the end of the current list
                ElseIf Right(CurrentValue, Len(NextValue)) = NextValue Then
                    Target.Value = Left(CurrentValue, Len(CurrentValue) - Len(NextValue) - 2)
                    'Remove the last selection and the comma and the comma and space before it
                
                'If last selection is already in the beginning or middle of list
                ElseIf InStr(1, CurrentValue, NextValue) > 0 Then
                    Target.Value = Replace(CurrentValue, NextValue & ", ", "")
                    'Remove last selection and comma and space after it

                'If the last selection is not a repeat, allow multiple selections separated by a comma and space
                Else
                    Target.Value = CurrentValue & ", " & NextValue
                
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    End If
    
    'Reprotect sheet
    ActiveSheet.Protect
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!